# Write a program to display the selected items in a list in the order of selection using Java AWT Components

Tags: java, queue, awt

So the basic idea of the problem is that we need to create a piece of code that will display the user a list of subjects to select from. The user can select multiple options within the list, and we need to display the output of options selected in the order in which the user has selected the option.

**So if the list goes:**

*Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4.*

**And the user selects in order of:**

*Item 2, Item 4, Item 1.*

Then we need to display the order in which the options have been selected.

Currently, I have created a piece of code that partially fulfills this requirement, yet the output is extremely weird and tough to explain...

if the user selects an item for the first time, the output comes up accurately, but the issues start when the user starts to de-select items and then re-select them too. When the user de-selects the item, it will remove it from the output list, but when the user goes to re-select the item, it will not show up on the output list at all. Again it's extremely confusing to explain in words or images, so I will be posting the code here for any of you guys to copy and execute on your own to be able to understand the absurd output.

I asked a friend of mine, how I could make it work and they suggested I use queues, but then no ideas come to mind considering certain inputs (such as de-selecting the second item when there are 4 total items selected) where a queue would completely break down.

**(NOTE: This code will only work with Java versions 1.8 and the versions before it because it requires the use of appletviewer which has been depreciated since versions 1.9 and ahead, please keep that in mind)**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code = "ListDemo" width = "500" height = "500"></applet>*/
public class ListDemo extends Applet implements ItemListener{
    List l1;
    String msg;
    int selected = 0;
    int ordered[] = new int[6];
    public void init(){
        l1 = new List(3, true);
        l1.add("Java");         l1.add("Advance Java");
        l1.add("OS");           l1.add("Python");
        l1.add("JavaScript");   l1.add("Data Structures");
        add(l1);
        l1.addItemListener(this);
        for(int i = 0; i < ordered.length; ordered[i++] = -1);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        repaint();
    }
    private void removeElement(int index){
        for(int i = index; i < selected; i++){
            ordered[i] = ordered[i++];
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        msg = "The Selected Subjects are: ";
        int indexes[] = l1.getSelectedIndexes();
        for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++){
            int j = 0;
            for(; j < ordered.length; j++){
                if(ordered[j] == indexes[i]){  break;   }
            }
            if(j == ordered.length){
                ordered[selected++] = indexes[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < selected; i++){
            int j = 0;
            for(; j < indexes.length; j++){
                if(ordered[i] == indexes[j]){  break;   }
            }
            if(j == indexes.length){
                selected--;
                removeElement(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < selected; System.out.println(l1.getItem(ordered[i++])));
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < selected; msg += l1.getItem(ordered[i++]) + " ");
        g.drawString(msg, 10, 200);
    }
}
```

I'm a novice programmer, please go a bit easy on me if I'm not following certain conventions, or if the naming of my variables isn't very great, or if I've made any dumb mistakes that should've been noticed. Any and all forms of input are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Applets are dead - we're not going to support them, it's time for your school to pull itself out of the dark ages.

You'll be lucky to find anyone who has much experience with AWT anymore, even Swing.  Time to move onto JavaFX.

Anyway, this will accomplish what you're trying to do, but you're going to have to figure out how it works and re-apply it to your solution

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JList<String> lstItems;
        private List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            model.addElement("Java");
            model.addElement("Advance Java");
            model.addElement("OS");
            model.addElement("Python");
            model.addElement("JavaScript");
            model.addElement("Data Structures");

            lstItems = new JList<>(model);

            add(new JScrollPane(lstItems));

            lstItems.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {                
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    int index = lstItems.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        String value = lstItems.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                        List<String> selectedValues = lstItems.getSelectedValuesList();

                        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(selectedItems);
                        temp.removeAll(selectedValues);
                        selectedItems.removeAll(temp);

                        if (selectedValues.contains(value)) {
                            selectedItems.add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            JButton btn = new JButton("Order");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, selectedItems);
                }
            });
            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }
}
```